# How to reset Office 2007/2010 (Outlook and Word) normal template back to default on Vista/Windows7

Tags: windows, windows-vista, microsoft-office-2007, microsoft-office-2010, templates

A friend has messed up email and word by changing the default font, colour and all sorts. She wants the defaults back.

I believe this can be done by deleting *Normal.dotm* (where ever it is hidden) but unfortunately I'm not leaning over her shoulder nor am I sure this will work.

Why has no one asked this question before? Apologise if it is a duplicate, but I can only see how to change templates and those instructions don't work if Word is open.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My Normal.dotm seems to be located in `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates`

Where `Username` is my User account name.

Windows 7 32bit
Office 2010 Pro

Word recreates the file if deleted, just like older versions. (tested)